# Change flag image after change language in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a multilanguage website. I want to switch to another lang with change flag image and switch button. How does it work?

Thank you for your help!

My code is a dropdown and I want change it to switch button with flag.

```
<form asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="returnUrl" name="returnUrl" value="@returnUrl" />
    <select id="culture"
            name="culture"
            class="form-control"
            onchange="this.form.submit();"
            asp-items="culturItems"
            asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">
    </select>
</form>
```

[website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvScq.png)

Comment: Stack Overflow does not exist to write your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a front-end solution. Here is an example. Store the pictures in the *images* folder under your *wwwroot*.

```
<form asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@returnUrl" />
    <button type="submit" name="culture" value="en" class="btn-language">
        <img src="~/images/En.png" alt="English" />
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="culture" value="fr" class="btn-language">
        <img src="~/images/Fr.png" alt="French" />
    </button>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in this way

```
<form asp-action="ChangeLanguage" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@returnUrl" />
@if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "fa-IR")
{
    <button id="myButton" type="submit" name="culture" value="en-US" class="btn-language" style="border:none;">
        <img id="myImg" src="/Imageflag/English.png" alt="English" width="25" height="20" />
    </button>
}
else if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name == "en-US")
{
    <button id="faBtn" type="submit" name="culture" value="fa-IR" class="btn-language" style="border:none;">
        <img src="/Imageflag/Iran.png" alt="فارسی" width="25" height="20" />
    </button>
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**